# How can I create a less redundant project structure?

Tags: structure

Currently I'm working on a webapp that has a structure roughly like this:

- model

  - user
  - robot
- service

  - user
  - robot
- web

  - controller

    - user
    - robot

I'm noticing a lot of redundancy in this structure. Is there any way that I could create a project structure that is less redundant?

Comment: This is good. The concept is to find your files very soon on debugging and this is ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea behind folders in a project is to encourage [separation of concerns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20separation%20of,code%20of%20a%20computer%20program.). Each folder should group code into separate functionalities.

Your folder structure seems fine, but I would suggest changing the name of the files so that you know exactly what you're dealing with.

Perhaps more like:

- model

  - user
  - robot
- service

  - userService
  - robotService
- web

  - userController
  - robotController

This way you know immediately that:

- model files show structure of entities but no functions or logic
- services deal with business logic only
- controllers deal with API interfaces